# SDL stiff movement

Tags: c++, sdl

i am making a pong game, lPad is left pad and rPad is the right pad, but i have a problem when any pad is moving up and when i release the up button and press down the pad stops for a while and then goes down, the other thing is i can't move both pads when pressing both controls(only one is moving) with this setup:

```
if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                    switch(e.key.keysym.sym) {

                    case SDLK_s:
                        lPad.y += 8;
                        if(lPad.y >= s.SCREEN_HEIGHT - lPad.getHeight()) {
                            lPad.y = s.SCREEN_HEIGHT - lPad.getHeight();
                        }
                        break;

                        case SDLK_w:
                        lPad.y -= 8;
                        if(lPad.y <= 0) {
                            lPad.y = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                        case SDLK_DOWN:
                        rPad.y += 8;
                        if(rPad.y >= s.SCREEN_HEIGHT - rPad.getHeight()) {
                            rPad.y = s.SCREEN_HEIGHT - rPad.getHeight();
                        }
                        break;

                        case SDLK_UP:
                        rPad.y -= 8;
                        if(rPad.y <= 0) {
                            rPad.y = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Any idea how to fix this and make it smooth ?

Comment: @zenith what do you mean ?

Comment: Think he means any more tabs and your code - indeed all your problems - will drift effortlessly off the right hand side of the screen...

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL)` as the function to get input. This way, you can get the entire state of the keyboard simultaneously and thus allow for parallel inputs. If you use the `while` loop, each event will get caught individually, and thus be choppy.

Here is some sample code on how to use it:

```
  const auto * keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

  while(!done) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
      if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        done = true;
      }    
    }

    SDL_PumpEvents();

    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {
      p1.set_speed(0, -60000 * delta.count());
    }
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) {
      p1.set_speed(0, 60000 * delta.count());
    }
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
      p1.set_speed(-60000 * delta.count(), 0);
    }
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
      p1.set_speed(60000 * delta.count(), 0);
    }
```

Also, might I suggest having a speed variable? Using pixels is not a good way to scale movement, as it depends on the resolution of the screen. Using something based on a time step is much more robust.

Comment: can you please tell me how set_speed() should work ?
and what is delta ?